# Python responses mock library error: 'has no attribute activate'

Tags: python, tdd, python-responses

I am using Python 3.6 and requests 2.19.

After initializing the virtual environment and installing the `responses` library with `pip install responses` successfully:

> Successfully installed cookies-2.2.1  responses-0.9.0

When I try to use it as described in [responses git page](https://github.com/getsentry/responses):

```
import responses
from src.controllers.user_controller import UserController

class UserControllerTest(TestCase):

    @responses.activate
    def test_get_address_by_zip_code_returns_address_for_valid_zip_code(self):
        responses.add(
            responses.GET, 
            'https://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/82200530',
            json= {
               'country': 'Test',
               'city': 'test city',
               'street' : 'some street'
            },
            status=200)
    
        self.user_controller = UserController()
        result = self.user_controller.get_address_by_zip_code(82200530)
        self.assertIsNotNone(result)
```

It throws an error :

> E   AttributeError: module 'responses' has no attribute 'activate'

All the other tests in this test class pass. This is the only one that uses `responses` and the only one that is failing.

Does anybody knows why responses it not working?

Comment: Just to make sure: You don't have a python file called responses lying around somewhere right? Because I cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: @FlyingTeller No, I don't. I cannot understand what's going on. I use it in other projects and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a responses.py file in my case and was getting same error.
I renamed same file post which this issue resolved